# Gulp src base not working?

Tags: handlebars.js, gulp

I have a bunch of examples that I'm building a distribution for. One of them uses Handlebars. Because of that I need to precompile them. I've built a gulp task for them as follows:

```
var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare = require('gulp-declare');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

...

gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src('examples/**/*.hbs', {base: 'examples/'})
    .pipe(handlebars())
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'App.templates',
      noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

However, even when supplying the `base` option it doesn't seem to retain the relative directory structure - the file always ends up in the root of `dist` - what did I do wrong here?

Comment: To clarify, you're expecting `templates.js` to end-up with a base directory borrowed from one of the original templates? Or are you expecting it to end-up in `dist/examples/`?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a problem with how you're specifying relative paths. They should be prefixed with `./`.

```javascript
gulp.src('./examples/**/*.hbs', {base: './examples'})
    ...
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```